Why is my Selenium script only scraping data for 7 matches on Forebet?
I'm working on a web scraping project using Selenium to scrape football match data from a sports prediction website (let's use EXAMPLE for FOREBET). However, my script only retrieves data for 7 matches, even though there are more matches listed on the webpage.
Here’s the relevant part of my code:
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import logging
import google_colab_selenium as gs
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from random import choice

# Configurations
request_interval = 2  # seconds
page_load_delay = 2  # seconds
base_url = "https://www.example.com/en/football-tips-and-predictions-for-today/predictions-1x2"

# User agents list (non-mobile)
user_agents = [
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.3',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; AS; rv:11.0) like Gecko',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.0.1 Safari/605.1.15',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.96 Safari/537.36'
]

# Configure logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

# Setup Chrome options and driver
def setup_selenium():
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
    options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
    options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")
    options.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")
    options.add_argument("--incognito")
    options.add_argument(f'--user-agent={choice(user_agents)}')
    driver = gs.Chrome(options=options)
    return driver

def get_page_content(url, driver, request_interval=2, page_load_delay=2):
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(request_interval)
    html_content = driver.page_source
    time.sleep(page_load_delay)
    return html_content

def parse_match_details(soup, driver):
    matches = []
    match_links = [a['href'] for a in soup.select('.contentmiddle a[itemprop="url"]')]
    for link in match_links:
        match_url = f"https://www.example.com{link}"
        html_content = get_page_content(match_url, driver)
        match_soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'lxml')
        if not match_soup:
            continue

        try:
            home_team_name = match_soup.select_one("[itemprop='homeTeam'] [itemprop='url'] span").text.strip()
            away_team_name = match_soup.select_one("[itemprop='awayTeam'] [itemprop='url'] span").text.strip()
            home_matches_played = match_soup.select_one(".os_played_games_main span[data-team='h']").text.strip()
            away_matches_played = match_soup.select_one(".os_played_games_main span[data-team='a']").text.strip()
            home_standing = match_soup.select_one("span.teamtableleft").text.strip()
            away_standing = match_soup.select_one("span.teamtableright").text.strip()
            match_time = match_soup.select_one("[itemprop='startDate'] div").text.strip()

            recent_matches = match_soup.select_one("div.os_goals_section3_container")
            home_and_away_goals = recent_matches

            def get_statistic(selector, data_team, data_stat):
                stat = home_and_away_goals.select_one(f"[data-team='{data_team}'][data-stat='{data_stat}'] span.__{selector}")
                return stat.text.strip() if stat else ""

            home_stats = {
                "Under 1.5": get_statistic("under", 'h', 'pc-ov1.5'),
                "Over 1.5": get_statistic("over", 'h', 'pc-ov1.5'),
                "Under 2.5": get_statistic("under", 'h', 'pc-ov2.5'),
                "Over 2.5": get_statistic("over", 'h', 'pc-ov2.5'),
                "Under 3.5": get_statistic("under", 'h', 'pc-ov3.5'),
                "Over 3.5": get_statistic("over", 'h', 'pc-ov3.5'),
                "Yes": get_statistic("under", 'h', 'bottom_chart'),
                "No": get_statistic("over", 'h', 'bottom_chart'),
            }

            away_stats = {
                "Under 1.5": get_statistic("under", 'a', 'pc-ov1.5'),
                "Over 1.5": get_statistic("over", 'a', 'pc-ov1.5'),
                "Under 2.5": get_statistic("under", 'a', 'pc-ov2.5'),
                "Over 2.5": get_statistic("over", 'a', 'pc-ov2.5'),
                "Under 3.5": get_statistic("under", 'a', 'pc-ov3.5'),
                "Over 3.5": get_statistic("over", 'a', 'pc-ov3.5'),
                "Yes": get_statistic("under", 'a', 'bottom_chart'),
                "No": get_statistic("over", 'a', 'bottom_chart'),
            }

            matches.append({
                "Match Link": match_url,
                "Home Team Name": home_team_name,
                "Away Team Name": away_team_name,
                "Home Matches Played": home_matches_played,
                "Home Standing": home_standing,
                "Away Matches Played": away_matches_played,
                "Away Standing": away_standing,
                "Match Time": match_time,
                **home_stats,
                **away_stats
            })
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(f"Error parsing {match_url}: {e}")

    return matches

def scrape_all_pages(start_url):
    all_matches = []
    next_page_url = start_url

    driver = setup_selenium()

    try:
        while next_page_url:
            html_content = get_page_content(next_page_url, driver)
            if not html_content:
                break

            soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'html.parser')
            matches = parse_match_details(soup, driver)
            all_matches.extend(matches)

            load_more_button = soup.select_one('#mrows span')
            if load_more_button:
                next_page_url = load_more_button.get('data-next-page-url')
                if next_page_url:
                    if not next_page_url.startswith('http'):
                        next_page_url = f"https://www.example.com{next_page_url}"
                    time.sleep(page_load_delay)
                else:
                    next_page_url = None
            else:
                next_page_url = None
    finally:
        driver.quit()

    return all_matches

def main():
    matches = scrape_all_pages(base_url)
    df = pd.DataFrame(matches)
    df.to_csv('football_matches.csv', index=False)
    print("Data saved to football_matches.csv")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

What could be causing this limitation, and how can I ensure that I scrape data for all the matches available on the page?

Hard to say what's happening without knowing the real website address

you can to replace example with forebet

Worked fine for me, so not sure what the issue is. Looking into this particular site further, it's not dynamically loaded. You can use simple requests to get the html and parse.
You'll have to debug and dig a bit, as some of the matches don't have some of the nodes you're searching for, so you need to perhaps make it more robust, but running this returned 58 of the 66 matches.
Code:
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import logging
import requests
from random import choice

# Configurations
request_interval = 2  # seconds
page_load_delay = 2  # seconds
base_url = "https://www.forebet.com/en/football-tips-and-predictions-for-today/predictions-1x2"

# User agents list (non-mobile)
user_agents = [
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.3',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; AS; rv:11.0) like Gecko',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.0.1 Safari/605.1.15',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.96 Safari/537.36'
]

# Configure logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)



def get_page_content(url, page_load_delay=2):
    headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/126.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}
    html_content = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text
    time.sleep(page_load_delay)
    return html_content

def parse_match_details(soup):
    matches = []
    match_links = [a['href'] for a in soup.select('.contentmiddle a[itemprop="url"]')]
    for link in match_links:
        print(link)
        match_url = f"https://www.forebet.com{link}"
        html_content = get_page_content(match_url)
        match_soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'lxml')
        if not match_soup:
            continue

        try:
            home_team_name = match_soup.select_one("[itemprop='homeTeam'] [itemprop='url'] span").text.strip()
            away_team_name = match_soup.select_one("[itemprop='awayTeam'] [itemprop='url'] span").text.strip()
            home_matches_played = match_soup.select_one(".os_played_games_main span[data-team='h']").text.strip()
            away_matches_played = match_soup.select_one(".os_played_games_main span[data-team='a']").text.strip()
            home_standing = match_soup.select_one("span.teamtableleft").text.strip()
            away_standing = match_soup.select_one("span.teamtableright").text.strip()
            match_time = match_soup.select_one("[itemprop='startDate'] div").text.strip()

            recent_matches = match_soup.select_one("div.os_goals_section3_container")
            home_and_away_goals = recent_matches

            def get_statistic(selector, data_team, data_stat):
                stat = home_and_away_goals.select_one(f"[data-team='{data_team}'][data-stat='{data_stat}'] span.__{selector}")
                return stat.text.strip() if stat else ""

            home_stats = {
                "Under 1.5": get_statistic("under", 'h', 'pc-ov1.5'),
                "Over 1.5": get_statistic("over", 'h', 'pc-ov1.5'),
                "Under 2.5": get_statistic("under", 'h', 'pc-ov2.5'),
                "Over 2.5": get_statistic("over", 'h', 'pc-ov2.5'),
                "Under 3.5": get_statistic("under", 'h', 'pc-ov3.5'),
                "Over 3.5": get_statistic("over", 'h', 'pc-ov3.5'),
                "Yes": get_statistic("under", 'h', 'bottom_chart'),
                "No": get_statistic("over", 'h', 'bottom_chart'),
            }

            away_stats = {
                "Under 1.5": get_statistic("under", 'a', 'pc-ov1.5'),
                "Over 1.5": get_statistic("over", 'a', 'pc-ov1.5'),
                "Under 2.5": get_statistic("under", 'a', 'pc-ov2.5'),
                "Over 2.5": get_statistic("over", 'a', 'pc-ov2.5'),
                "Under 3.5": get_statistic("under", 'a', 'pc-ov3.5'),
                "Over 3.5": get_statistic("over", 'a', 'pc-ov3.5'),
                "Yes": get_statistic("under", 'a', 'bottom_chart'),
                "No": get_statistic("over", 'a', 'bottom_chart'),
            }

            matches.append({
                "Match Link": match_url,
                "Home Team Name": home_team_name,
                "Away Team Name": away_team_name,
                "Home Matches Played": home_matches_played,
                "Home Standing": home_standing,
                "Away Matches Played": away_matches_played,
                "Away Standing": away_standing,
                "Match Time": match_time,
                **home_stats,
                **away_stats
            })
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(f"Error parsing {match_url}: {e}")

    return matches

def scrape_all_pages(start_url):
    all_matches = []
    next_page_url = start_url

    try:
        while next_page_url:
            html_content = get_page_content(next_page_url)
            if not html_content:
                break

            soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'html.parser')
            matches = parse_match_details(soup)
            all_matches.extend(matches)

            load_more_button = soup.select_one('#mrows span')
            if load_more_button:
                next_page_url = load_more_button.get('data-next-page-url')
                if next_page_url:
                    if not next_page_url.startswith('http'):
                        next_page_url = f"https://www.forebet.com{next_page_url}"
                    time.sleep(page_load_delay)
                else:
                    next_page_url = None
            else:
                next_page_url = None
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

    return all_matches

def main():
    matches = scrape_all_pages(base_url)
    df = pd.DataFrame(matches)
    df.to_csv('football_matches.csv', index=False)
    print("Data saved to football_matches.csv")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Output:
print(df.head().to_string())
                                                                          Match Link    Home Team Name  Away Team Name Home Matches Played           Home Standing Away Matches Played           Away Standing            Match Time Under 1.5 Over 1.5 Under 2.5 Over 2.5 Under 3.5 Over 3.5 Yes No
0  https://www.forebet.com/en/football/matches/newcastle-jets-western-united-2078803    Newcastle Jets  Western United                  27  10th place in A-League                  27  11th place in A-League  24/07/2024 11:25 GMT       22%      78%       37%      63%       52%      48%       
1   https://www.forebet.com/en/football/matches/edgeworth-eagles-new-lambton-2014716  Edgeworth Eagles     New Lambton                  17               3rd place                  17              10th place  24/07/2024 12:00 GMT       24%      76%       35%      65%       88%      12%       
2     https://www.forebet.com/en/football/matches/gimpo-citizen-seoul-e-land-2017350     GimPo Citizen    Seoul E-Land                  25               7th place                  23               6th place  24/07/2024 12:30 GMT        9%      91%       30%      70%       70%      30%       
3     https://www.forebet.com/en/football/matches/cheongju-fc-asan-mugunghwa-2017351       Cheongju FC  Asan Mugunghwa                  24               8th place                  23               3rd place  24/07/2024 12:30 GMT       22%      78%       48%      52%       65%      35%       
4       https://www.forebet.com/en/football/matches/ansan-greeners-fc-anyang-2017352    Ansan Greeners       FC Anyang                  24              13th place                  23               1st place  24/07/2024 12:30 GMT       35%      65%       57%      43%       83%      17%       


How are you managing to bypass CloudFlare? When I run this code (strict copy'n'paste) I get HTTP 403 and associated CloudFlare content. I think the viability of this code may be affected by the client IP address origin

you using a vpn?

I tried both with and without VPN and got no results in either case

odd. Ya not sure. The other option i suppose is you can look at cloudscraper to use in stead of requests

Since I am using Colab, I installed this google-colab-selenium package, which includes undetected ChromeDriver to handle Cloudflare's bot detection:
%pip install -q google-colab-selenium[undetected] torch

I configured Selenium to use a headless Chrome browser and included various options to mimic a real user's browsing behavior, like setting a random user agent from a list of user agents:
import google_colab_selenium as gs
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from random import choice

user_agents = [
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.3',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; AS; rv:11.0) like Gecko',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.0.1 Safari/605.1.15',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.96 Safari/537.36']

def setup_selenium():
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
    options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
    options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")
    options.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")
    options.add_argument("--incognito")
    options.add_argument(f'--user-agent={choice(user_agents)}')
    driver = gs.Chrome(options=options)
    return driver

Next, I used Selenium to navigate to the target URL and retrieve the page source. This helps bypass Cloudflare by simulating a real browser session:
    def get_page_content(url, driver, request_interval=2, page_load_delay=2):
        driver.get(url)
        time.sleep(request_interval)
        html_content = driver.page_source
        time.sleep(page_load_delay)
        return html_content

As for HTML parsing, I used  BeautifulSoup.
